# The number of solutions for n raised to a complex exponent

Tags: complex-numbers

My understanding is that there is one and only one solution when solving for $z$ when $z = n^s$, where $s$ is a complex number of the form $a + bi$.  However, there are many solutions to $z$ when $z^{1/s} = n$.  It seems the solutions should be the same for $z$ in either case.  My first question: is this correct or is it an incorrect/incomplete understanding?

Assuming this is correct, my second question is on how this differs with real number exponents.  For example, $z$ has $m$ solutions when $z = n^{1/m}$ and there are also $m$ solutions to $z$ when $z^m = n$.  In fact, the solutions are the same for $z$ when solving for either form.  Why do we not have this same symmetry with complex exponents?

Comment: Well... No. The same issue of definition that arises when you try to define $(x+yi)^{a+bi}$ arises when $x=1$ and $y=0$. In fact, $$1=\exp(2k\pi i)\implies 1^{a+bi}=\exp(-2kb\pi+2k\pi ai)$$ but $\exp(-2kb\pi+2k\pi ai)$ depends (even in absolute value) on which $k\in\Bbb Z$ you choose, while $1$ doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your analogy with the real case isn't exactly correct.

Lets imagine what happens when "solving" (or just calculating) the value of $z=n^s$ when $s$ is complex.  You haven't specified what $n$ is, so I'll just assume it's complex.  If it's real there's just a slight modification in the argument.

Any complex number can be written in the form of $re^{i\theta}$, which is known as the *polar form* of the complex number.  Writing $z=x+iy$ is known as the *rectangular form*.  Now, I will write $n$ in polar form as $n=re^{i\theta}$, and $s$ in rectangular form as $s=x+iy$.  Taking the exponential, we have that $$n^s=\left( re^{i\theta}\right)^{x+iy}=r^{x+iy}e^{i\theta(x+iy)}=e^{\ln(r)(x+iy)}e^{i\theta x-\theta y}=e^{(\ln(r)x-\theta y)+i(\ln(r)y+\theta x)}$$
Each of $r$, $x$, $\theta$, and $y$ are just real constants.  So, this simplifies to $e^{a+bi}$ for some positive real constants $a$ and $b$.  This is a unique complex number, and while the complex exponential is $2\pi i$ periodic (so $e^{a+bi}=e^{a+bi+2\pi i}=e^{a+bi+2\pi ik}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).  But, the fact remains that this is just some specific complex number.

The reverse situation isn't true at all.  By this, I mean that, given a specific $z_0$, finding the $n$ such that $z_0=n^s$ generally has multiple solutions.  Contrary to your assertion though, this is true in the real case also.  To see this, consider the real function $y=x^2$.  We know beforehand that given some $x$, this outputs a unique $y$.  So, in our case of inverses (given a $y_0$, is $x$ such that $y_0=x^2$ unique?) has multiple answers as well.  Let's consider a specific case of $y_0=9$.  Which $x$ are there so $x^2=9$?  Clearly $x=3$ is an answer, but so is x=-3$.

Often when discussing the square root (the inverse function for $x^2$), one mentions the *principle square root*.  This just means that the inverse of $y=x^2$ can either be $x=\sqrt{y}$ or $x=-\sqrt{y}$.  This is because the inverse of the function $y=x^2$ is what's known as *multi-valued*.  When working with multivalued functions, it can often be desirable to specify which of the (potentially infinite) choices for it through a process known as making a *branch cut*.  I won't go into these too much, I'm just mentioning them in case you want to investigate further.

Comment: This answer assumes there is only one polar representation for $n$... and this is not true as we know that a full circle rotation gives us the same number.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. To clarify, with real exponents I understand that there are multiple roots and that the positive real root is called the principal root. My question is more focused on the complex exponents. To clarify, you write "finding the n such that z = n^s generally has multiple solutions," which I'm aware of and mentioned in my original question. I want to know if there is only one z when z = n^s. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The function that takes $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in\mathbb{C}$ to $n^s$ is $\exp(s\log n)$, a very useful convention.  For fractional real $s$, such as $s={1\over 2}$, one can I suppose complicate things and say that the function is multivalued, but I am not sure anything is gained.

If you are instead attempting to find *all* $z$ such that $z^{1/s}=n$, there will often be multiple solutions.  For example, if $s={1\over 2}$, so that the equation is $z^2=n$, obviously if $z$ is a solution so is $-z$.

If now $n$ is complex (not necessarily in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}^+$), it turns out that $\log n$ is not uniquely defined, and therefore $n^s$ as defined above has issues.  For example, $\log i$ is any number $u$ such that $\exp(u)=i$, which means $u$ can be $i(\pi/2+2\pi m)$ for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Again, if you were seeking complication you could say "ah, even when $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we could make $\log n$ multivalued," and indeed we could, but not much is gained thereby.

Humpty-Dumpty said "When *I* use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean -- neither more nor less."  That is how mathematicians think -- remember, the novelist who created Humpty-Dumpty was a mathematics don.  Over the years conventions have grown up which are useful and convenient, such as $\log x$ having exactly one value for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, or  the definition of $n^s$ in terms of exponentials given above.